# Resteasy Netty Server not handshaken after first client disconnection

Tags: java, ssl, jax-rs, netty, resteasy

I have an issue using NettyJaxrsServer with SSL. The first request succeed and subsequent ones timeout. Typically, if I use curl to send an HTTPS request, only the first call passes. I checked with wireshark to see what is happening. The server performs the handshake only for the first request. For the second request the client sends a "Hello" message, and the server do not continue the handshake. It seems like the server is keeping an SSL session even after the client disconnection.

[image]

I verified the code and for each client connection, a new SSLHandler is inserted in the client pipeline but using the same SSLEngine.

```
final SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
engine.setUseClientMode(false);
bootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
               ch.pipeline().addFirst(new SslHandler(engine));
               ch.pipeline().addLast(channelHandlers.toArray(new ChannelHandler[channelHandlers.size()]));
               ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
               ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(maxRequestSize));
               ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
               ch.pipeline().addLast(new RestEasyHttpRequestDecoder(dispatcher.getDispatcher(), root, RestEasyHttpRequestDecoder.Protocol.HTTPS));
               ch.pipeline().addLast(new RestEasyHttpResponseEncoder());
               ch.pipeline().addLast(eventExecutor, new RequestHandler(dispatcher));
           }
        })
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, backlog)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
```

From Netty documentation, I understand that a new SSLEngine should be used for each new client connection:

> Restarting the session
>
> To restart the SSL session, you must remove the existing closed SslHandler from the ChannelPipeline, insert a new SslHandler with a new SSLEngine into the pipeline, and start the handshake process as described in the first section.

Can someone explain this behavior? or is this a bug in Netty resteasy server?

Used version: resteasy-netty4 3.0.11.Final